# Gimp (Scheme) How do you script / automate "Fit Image in Window"?

Tags: view, scheme, zooming, gimp

How do you script this menu action in Gimp (Scheme)?

> View -> Zoom -> **Fit Image in Window**

I haven't found an appropriate method in the procedure browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't. By design the scripts and plugins cannot act on the UI itself.